# is this grammar right?

Tags: grammar

We are looking to use this text, as a headline on our sustainability page, on our website.

As coworker asked if "sustainably" was grammatically correct. I am unsure.

> TCS believes that thinking sustainably will make our future stronger, to think globally and act locally through a variety of green initiatives

Is the word `sustainable` used correctly, is it even a word?

Comment: Just missing a subject. You can leave a lot out of headlines, but a subject is quite important, I think.

Comment: You didn't give us the whole sentence. That fragment COULD be part of a grammatically correct sentence.

Comment: ok I updated the sentence, thanks fro the quick responses

Comment: Proofreading and correction are off-topic.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As Mitch notes, this is not an editing service; if you have a specific question about *why* you think the grammar might be incorrect, we can help you, but otherwise this question is "too localized" in the old parlance to be of future help to anyone, which SE discourages.

Comment: Ok I see, I think our main question then was is `sustainably` being used correctly, or is it a word at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TCS believes that thinking sustainably will make our future stronger

Up to there, it is a correct and understandable sentence.

However:

> , to think globally and act locally through a variety of green initiatives

Seems to dangle at the end, and I don't seem to be able to connect it it the previous sentence logically.

Unless in some way, the *act* of making the future string somehow enables one *to think globally*, there seems no connection.

The *to* does not connected it to *believes*, I can't connect it to anything else.

A verb seems to be missing in that last part - do you mean something like this?

> TCS believes that thinking sustainably will make our future stronger, and endeavours to think globally and act locally through a variety of green initiatives.

<s>is there a kickback for helping with TCS copywriting? :P</s>

Comment: Thanks I realize now my question seemed like hey can you do work for me, I suppose I should have asked the question I just added to the comments in the main post. Is sustainably used correctly

Comment: @ScottC I think sustainably is fine :) But I would take a look at the dangling _or_ :) No worries, if I can say I contributed to TCS' success, it'll look good on my CV :D

Comment: I went with "..., striving to think globally..." but I did appreciate the tip `A verb seems to be missing in that last part`